# Inkscape: Restore the original aspect ratio or the size of an imported image

Tags: inkscape

Is it possible to restore the original aspect ratio or original size of an imported image in Inkscape ? If yes, how to do it ?

Answer (score 6):

If you imported an image and then accidentally modified its aspect ratio, you can restore it from the XML editor:

1. Select the image
2. Call the XML editor. The object should have `height` and `width` properties.
3. Select the `height` attribute and delete it (using the red cross icon above).
4. Do the same with `width`.
5. Now the image should have the original aspect ratio (and maybe also size).

Comment: It worked =) Just note that *XML Editor* is accessible via *Edit* menu.

Comment: it worked, but I don't need to open XML editor, just open the image properties.